# Can anyone decipher this SQL Stack Trace?

Tags: sql, exception, grails, driver, stack-trace

I have a stack trace that is not making any sense to me. I think the essence of it is the "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" part, but I've registered a driver and I'm not using a Datasource. If it helps, I am using a SQL Anywhere 10 driver (ianywhere). Does anyone have any ideas?

```
2013-02-15 13:16:58,076 [http-apr-80-exec-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SQLException occurred when processing request: [GET] /Booklist/booklist/show
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified. Stacktrace follows:
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    at ianywhere.ml.jdbcodbc.jdbc3.IDriver.connect(IDriver.java:490)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)
    at booklist.Book.getClassesWithBooks(Book.groovy:22)
    at booklist.BooklistController.show(BooklistController.groovy:11)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

edit: The thing is, this works just fine on my local development machine, but as soon as we build a War and put it on the tomcat server, this lovely error pops up

Comment: What is your JDBC URL?

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the response. The URL is as follows:

    `DriverManager.registerDriver( (Driver) Class.forName("ianywhere.ml.jdbcodbc.jdbc3.IDriver").newInstance() );`

        

`def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:ianywhere:Driver=SQL Anywhere 10;LINKS=TCPIP(IP=[IP-address];PORT=[PORT]);ServerName=[server-name];databaseName=[db-name];uid=dba;pwd=[our-password]")`

Answer (score 0):

I think the trace is pretty clear.  Look at the first error message:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified. Stacktrace follows:
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

The ODBC driver is not set up correctly.  It is pointing to a database that doesn't exist.  Or, perhaps to a server that doesn't exist.

Comment: The thing is, this works just fine on my local development machine, but as soon as we build a War and put it on the tomcat server, this lovely error pops up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a `Grails` configuration issue. Check the environment you're building the war (development, production) and the related configuration in DataSource.groovy. [Grails Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSourcesAndEnvironments)